# Starting SoapUI in Linux

Tags: maven, ubuntu, soapui

If i download SoapUI and install it, i chose "run SoapUI" in the installation process and then the program starts.

But how do i start soapui normally in Linux in this case Ubuntu? Right now, i just reinstall it again to get the "run" button in order to start the program.

Comment: Can you give more details? How do you run the `SoapUI` runtime? Using `java -jar` command? I see there is an option to run it through the `./soapui.sh` executable.

Comment: Your questions is very confusing. Your first line is the answer to the question in the second line! I do not understand what you are doing with `java -jar ...` or with Maven. Have you tried the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/

Comment: @SiKing I simply do not know how to start the program and the documentation did not tell me either. Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation, one of the steps asks you:

> Where should SoapUI create symlinks to the executables?

By default `/usr/local/bin` is selected.

Also, one of the steps asks you to create a desktop icon.

Lastly, as normal part of the installation, an app menu item was created in the group "Other".

So to start SoapUI "normally", you have several options:

1. In your apps menu, find the group "Other", and there you will see the item "SoapUI 5.6.0". Click on that.
2. Double-click the desktop icon, also named "SoapUI 5.6.0".
3. In the location where you created the symlinks, there will be an executable `SoapUI-5.6.0`, which you can run from the commandline.

This is all basic usage of your computer and your operating system. Perhaps you should find some [introductory tutorials how to use your computer](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/getting-started.html).